# Comparing2 different Javascript Constructor method

Tags: javascript, constructor

I am new to JavaScript and found that the 2 different methods below are able to instantiate object.

I looked the object created from both constructors and it appears to be same to me.

But I am not sure what is the difference between these 2 method? and in which scenario a method is better than another?

Can anyone please explain? Thank you.

Person1.js

```
function Person1(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.initialize();
}

Person1.prototype.initialize = function (todoName) {
    console.log("Initalize function Person 1 class"+this);
    f1(this);
}

function f1(caller) {
    console.log("F1 Person 1 class"+this);
    console.log(this);
    console.log("F1 Person 1 class caller"+caller);
    console.log(caller);
}
```

Person2.js

```
var Person2 = (function(){

function Person2(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.initialize();
}

Person2.prototype.initialize = function (todoName) {
    console.log("Initalize function Person 2 class"+this);
    f1(this);
}

function f1(caller) {
    console.log("F1 Person 2 class"+this);
    console.log(this);
    console.log("F1 Person 2 class caller"+caller);
    console.log(caller);
}

return Person2;
})();
```

Instantiate the object with this code:

```
var p1 = new Person1("P1");
var p2 = new Person2("P2");

console.log("Completed ");
console.log("P1 ");
console.log(p1);
console.log("P2 ");
console.log(p2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Person2` is wrapped in what's called an **immediately invoked funciton expression** (or IIFE). You'll notice that at the end, it returns `Person2`, and that's why the assignment on the first line of the example works.

The reason you would consider using this method is that wrapping up code in an IIFE keeps you global scope clean (meaning, that in a browser for example, the `window` object doesn't get cluttered with a bunch of global properties).

As a beginner, I might go for the `Person1` method, as it's visually simpler and easier to track what's going on. As you progress, however, keep the above in mind and think about what's best for the maintainability of your code base.